# search htm files for pair of words between BR tags

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, grep, html-parsing

I have a collection of 500+ files that contain many <br />  tags used to separate data elements.

For example, file001.htm contains:

```
<br \/>J Smith<br \/>B Jones<br \/>john smith betty Jones<br \/>Henry Peterson<br \/>jones Smith<br \/>
```

For a single file; this command will find data elements with both "Smith" and "Jones" (ignore case and order):

```
sed 's/<br \/>/\n/g' file001.htm | grep -i Smith | grep -i Jones
```

which produces:
john smith betty Jones
jones Smith

But when I change file001.htm to file*.htm; I get many matches and I don't know which file contains those matches.

I'd like a command-line solution that searches all files for two words between <br /> tags in any order and output tells me which files contain matching data.

Comment: What you're trying to do, finding strings in a structured data file like HTML, is not something you can do reliably with regular expressions. You should be using a proper HTML parser in your programming language of choice.

Comment: Your sed script doesn't produce the output you say it does, please check it.

Comment: Using a regex to parse html will invoke the wrath of the elders.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1216776

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you asked for if your input really is as regular as you show, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `IGNORECASE`:

```
$ awk -v RS='<br [\\\\]/>' -v OFS=': ' -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    /smith/ && /jones/ { print FILENAME, $0 }
' file*.htm
file001.htm: john smith betty Jones
file001.htm: jones Smith
```

Note that as written in your sed script and so copied above `smith` matches `smithereens`, etc. If that's a problem then you can add word boundaries to avoid such partial match issues if your target strings are all word-constituent characters:

```
$ awk -v RS='<br [\\\\]/>' -v OFS=': ' -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    /\<smith\>/ && /\<jones\>/ { print FILENAME, $0 }
' file*.htm
file001.htm: john smith betty Jones
file001.htm: jones Smith
```